# how do I get -P full in SML "Run in command" in textmate

Tags: textmate, sml

How do I include the mosml -P full into "Run in command" textmate for SML?

and is it possible to have a "live" terminal window within textmate to test bits of code sort of like in emacs?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Textmate seems not to support REPL(read–eval–print loop). I use the SML/NJ in Sublime Text. It works fine and is easy to set up. You may want a try.